# Automation (Smart Home): General Information / Devices controller by WiFi

Tags: smart-home

I would like to post this topic as general *Q&A* topic.

I would like to start changing my home into a ***smart*** one. I am software developer, unfortunately I haven't got experience with Embedded (IoT) Software so far.

More precisely I came up with idea of creating **home** with any **device** (applicane) a smart one which I would **controll** **using** my **mobile** connected to my **Web** **Server** (Web Application).

Web Application would be central unit, which would keep all necessery data (flags or so) for any unit.

I would be able to change devices' settings using **mobile**, changing specific data in Web Application's database.

According to this setup, I assume that I would need any **device** connected to **WiFi  module** in order to read settings (flags etc) from Web Application.

So here comes out question: Would I need **microcontroller** for **each** **device** because of gathering device (for example Light Bulb along with WiFi module)?

Where can I buy home devices that have interface which can be programmed (cheap/expensive) manually, I guess I don't need device that comes up with application which controll only that device, I am building my own mobile application which controlles whole home?

In which programming languages, frameworks, technologies should I start doing this? (asking about home devices only)

In general, how do developers realize projects like this, I assume that I am not the only one doing this staff.

Any additional general information / experience / tip is more than welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Exchange is a question/answer system, it is not a good place to hold discussions. This question is currently far too broad

Comment: Go read for a few days at https://forum.universal-devices.com.  This entire topic is covered.... and then some...

Comment: In general, not all devices could be controlled. You could at best power on and off those devices using relays or contractors.  It is costly, at the moment, to replace dump devices with smart ones. 

As smart devices consume energy even it is not "turned o ". I would suggest you control the devices which consume the most energy, such as refrigerators,  air conditioning systems, heaters, pumps, etc.  

However, there is no unified protocol among those devices. You may need a gateway to link all those devices using custom drives.

I hope this clarify certain doubts that you have.